# Discovery about regular $3m$-gons: $3d=n\ell$ where $d$ is the longest diagonal, $\ell$ is the side, and $n$ is number of sides

Tags: geometry

I have found something new about regular polygons. Can you please check it?

> For a regular polygon with $n=3m$ sides,
> $$3d=n\ell$$
> where $d$ is the longest diagonal and $\ell$ is the length of a side.

It, as I see, is true for regular polygons starting from regular triangles and continuing to polygons whose number of sides are successive multiples of $3$.

Comment: if it is true can i use it in my numericals

Comment: If we take the unit square then $d=\sqrt 2$, $n=4$, and $l=1$, yes?

Comment: It is not true for a regular pentagon.

Comment: What does it mean to "continue with sussive $3$ sides"? Are you skipping over squares and pentagons and going from triangles to hexagons (and then to $9$-sided, $12$-sided, etc. polygons)?

Comment: Please edit your post for clarity.  As it stands, your claim is not generally true.  Did you omit some assumptions?

Comment: Curiously enough ... If you let $n\to\infty$, then $d\to 2r$ ($r$-radius of the circumscribed circle), and $nl\to 2\pi r$ (circumference) so really you have that, with large $n$, keeping $r$ constant, this will be valid: $\pi d\approx nl$. Is the number $3$ some sort of the first approximation to $\pi$?

Comment: yes  i am using it for 3 sided then 6 sided the 9 sided regular polygons and so on.

Comment: For $360$-sided polygon inscribed in circle of radius $1$, we have $nl=360\cdot 2\sin(30')=6.28310556\ldots$ and $3d=6$. However, $\pi d=6.2831853\ldots$

Comment: so please tell me can use it or not

Comment: The claim is generally false so no, you can't use it.

Answer (score 2):

This is not generally valid, but for large $n$ you will have that the ratio $nl/d$ approaches $\pi=3.14159\ldots$. The reason: if you fix the radius $r$ of the circumscribed circle, you will get, as $n\to\infty$:

- $nl\to 2\pi r$ as the circumference of the polygon approaches the circumference of the circle
- $d\to 2r$ as the largest diagonal approaches the diameter of the circle.

Thus $\frac{nl}{d}\to\frac{2\pi r}{2r}=\pi$.

So, in a sense, for large $n$, you will have $\pi d\approx nl$ (rather than $3d=nl$).

If it is of interest, we can go further to estimate the error made in the above approximation of $\pi\approx\frac{nl}{d}$ (depending on $n$), but at least we have now corrected the constant term ;)

Hope this helps.